# handeling errors in the if or else part?

Tags: php, error-handling

I usually don't think about it, but I'm just curious if there's any reason to do it in one or the other part of the script?

Like:

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    /*  handle the error  */
} else {
    /*  do something productive  */
}
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    /*  do something productive  */
} else {
    /*  handle the error  */
}
```

Like a script I'm working on now; 
First I need to check for empty required fields. After that I need to see if the provided name already exists or not. Then I need to make sure at least 1 ingredient is provided (for the recipe). If those checks out ok; I can continue to make sure each ingredient is available for the relation table. Finally I can add the actual recipe. After that I can add other associated stuff.

As you can see, I have a lot of `if/else`-statements going on. So back to my question; is it better take care of the errors at the top/beginning (`if`), or at the bottom/end (`else`)?

*I might not be doing this error handling thing correct at all. Just came to think of the `try/throw/catch`-statements. But don't really know how those works...*

Comment: I would say: It is up to you. Personally I prefer two things: End a script/method as soon as possible (so first check if you have to do anything before doing something) and following a logical pattern, aka are you looking for non empty variable for later use? Then use `!empty()`, etc. (so the code speaks as much for itself as possible)

Answer (score 2):

As noted in other answers, it hardly matters; but, there are two factors which will theoretically affect computation time:

- If the "if" condition is true, the else is skipped (as you likely know) saving some computation time. So, you'll have a faster average computational speed by putting the condition you expect to be true most often in the "if" condition.
- This one is even more negligible, but theoretically true: "!" is an operator, and additional operations take additional time; so, avoiding an unnecessary use of "!" is preferable.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Therefore I've allways put what I expected to happen in the "if" condition. But then I thought about that php reads each line, character by character, down the script and execute accordenly. Since the error handling is much less code - most of the times - than the actual process, I thought it would be less code to go trough.. But on the other hand, if coded properly, you would never touch the "else" condition because the script will be done and exited before it reaches so far...

Comment: By the way. In my example the two factors you mentioned does not get along :P

Comment: Well, the first factor is of greater consequence!

Answer (score 0):

They are functionally the same, but my preference is for your second example where you handle the error ever `else`.  The reason for this is because I like to have the expected/desired/non-error be what shows up first.  I find that it makes the code more readable; someone following up on your code afterwards will have an easier time figuring out what you're wanting to accomplish.